# Count number of appearances of different values

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
set.seed(5)
round<-rep(1:5,4)
players<-rep(1:2, c(10,10))
decs<-sample(1:3,20,replace=TRUE)
game<-rep(rep(1:2,c(5,5)),2)
gamematrix<-cbind(players,game,round,decs)
gamematrix



        players game round decs **decs1_sum**    **decs2_sum** **decs3_sum**
 [1,]       1    1     1    1       3                  0              2
 [2,]       1    1     2    3       3                  0              2
 [3,]       1    1     3    3       3                  0              2 
 [4,]       1    1     4    1       3                  0              2
 [5,]       1    1     5    1       2                  0              2 
 [6,]       1    2     1    3       2                  1              3
 [7,]       1    2     2    2       2                  1              3
 [8,]       1    2     3    3       2                  1              3
 [9,]       1    2     4    3       2                  1              3
[10,]       1    2     5    1       2                  1              3 
[11,]       2    1     1    1       3                  2              0 
[12,]       2    1     2    2       3                  2              0
[13,]       2    1     3    1       3                  2              0 
[14,]       2    1     4    2       3                  2              0
[15,]       2    1     5    1       3                  2              0
[16,]       2    2     1    1       1                  2              2
[17,]       2    2     2    2       1                  2              2 
[18,]       2    2     3    3       1                  2              2 
[19,]       2    2     4    2       1                  2              2 
[20,]       2    2     5    3       1                  2              2
```

Now I would like to create the following three variables, decs1_sum, decs2_sum, decs3_sum, which sums the number of appearances of each of the decisions, for each player in each game. So the output should be, as presented above..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the `tidyverse` suite of packages:

```
game_summary <- gamematrix %>%
  data.frame %>%
  group_by(players, game) %>%
  summarize(
    decs1_sum = sum(decs == 1),
    decs2_sum = sum(decs == 2),
    decs3_sum = sum(decs == 3)
 )
gamematrix <- gamematrix %>% 
  data.frame %>%
  left_join(game_summary, by = c("players", "game"))
```

If you aren't familiar with the pipe operator (`%>%`), it simply enters the result from the last function as the first element of the next function, which makes it easier to see how the data frame is modified at each step.